# Only allow rbash user to su

Tags: linux, bash, su

I want to have a user that has set rbash as its default shell to only use the command `su`. I have tried to create a folder "bin" in the home directory of the user and copied the binary su (/bin/su) into this folder. Then I set the path of this user to `$HOME/bin`, but when using su I can not switch to another account.

Does su rely on other binaries, which are blocked in this case?
The error when using su is the same that happens if the password is incorrect. Does su uses cat or something like this to view the shadow file?

Which binary do I have to give the user to allow him to su to other users?

bin directory:

```
/home/user/bin# ls -al
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 21 19:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Aug 20 22:44 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 59424 Aug 20 21:32 su
```

Comment: Please add `ls -l` output for the `$HOME/bin` directory to your question. It may be something trivial as `chown root su` or `chmod u+s su`

Comment: See: `ldd $(which su)`

Comment: What do i do with the output of ldd ....?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move `su` executable at all. You could set `su` access rights in such way that only one user (and root) will be able to run it.

Run following commands from root user and from directory where `su` file is located.

Firstly set file owner to user that you want to grant exclusive access:

```
chown USER_NAME su
```

Then remove e(x)ecution access from all except owner, i.e. remove `x` right from (o)ther and (g)roup:

```
chmod og-x su
```